# How to disable a module dependents module? Not the module but the feature

Tags: 7, drush, views

Hello I have the module **BEF better exposed filters** installed and enabled and together with it is the *BEF Test Content* module (**feature of BEF better exposed filters moduke**).

I just enable the features so **BEF Test Content** for making tests and now when I want to disable it shows on the screen like red and when i try to disable and save configuration... i can not...

also i tried through drush by using:

```
drush dis better_exposed_filters
```

**but logically it says that it will disable the BEF Test Content module extension but also it will disable together with the BEF Better exposed filters too...**

is there a way to disable only the dependent module? how about with drush?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean

> Can I disable/uninstall the BEF module without first disabling/uninstalling the BEF Test Content module (or any other modules that depend on it)

Then no, that's not possible.

"Dependency" means that one module cannot function without the other. In this case, the BEF Test Content module will be unable to function unless the BEF module is also installed and enabled.

Drupal understands this constraint, and makes sure the you can't break your site by removing functionality from one module that is required by another.

If you mean

> Can I disable/uninstall the BEF Test Content module without disabling/uninstalling the BEF module

Then yes, you can either disable/uninstall it through the UI as normal, or use Drush. BEF doesn't have a dependency on BEF Test Content, so Drupal won't stop you from removing it.

The only caveat to that is if there are *other* constraints introduced by the BEF Test Content module. For example, if it provides a field type which is in use, the module cannot be disabled until the field is detached from all entities. But the admin UI will tell you explicitly if that's the case